# using Daterange after displaying html table from CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to filter date range using jQuery UI, it works on static  HTML table, but I'm displaying my table from my CSV file.

So first I import the CSV data in my JavaScript code then I write some html content using JavaScript (with innerhtml).

My problem is: filtering my data using datepicker() in jQuery doesn't work correctly, this is the code I'm using:

```
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */

$(document).ready(function () {
   $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
         var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
         var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
         var startDate = new Date(data[4])
         if (min == null && max == null) {
            return true;
         }
         if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
            return true;
         }
         if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
            return true;
         }
         if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
            return true;
         }
         return false;
      }
   );


   $("#min").datepicker({
      onSelect: function () {
         table.draw();
      },
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
   });
   $("#max").datepicker({
      onSelect: function () {
         table.draw();
      },
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
   });
   var table = $('#example').DataTable();

   // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
   $('#min, #max').change(function () {
      table.draw();
   });
});
```

When I try to filter my data (4th column of my table) using datepicker, I got strange result: it display few rows after writing a date in the start-date input, and displays nothing when I write date in final-date input.

I heard like datepicker() is loaded only when the document is loaded but my JS code is supposed to write all my CSV data in a table.